# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index x, size is y

Tags: android, spinner, android-adapter, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an activity where there are 2 spinners. I fill the spinners with lists taken from an xml file like this one :

```
<outil id="1" name="Décompacteur">
    <travail id="1">Travail au sol</travail>
    <travail id="1001">Autre</travail>
</outil>
<outil id="2" name="Cultivateur">
    <travail id="3">Travail au sol</travail>
    <travail id="1002">Autre</travail>
</outil>
```

In another activity, I can change the file from which I build the lists.

My problem is : I select a tool (outil) at the end of a long list of tools, for example position = 6. Then I change the file, and the tool list now has only 4 items. I set a new adapter :

```
listNameOutil = getOutilNameList(listOutilObject);
adapterOutil = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinners_base, listNameOutil);
adapterOutil.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner_outil.setAdapter(adapterOutil);
```

But I still get an error, and I don't know where it comes from provided there is no "caused by" in the stack trace... Please note that I also do a `spinner_outil.setSelection(positionSaved);`. At first, I was trying to catch the exception on this line but it seems that it's not this line which is the problem.

Any ideas to solve this?

Here is the Stack trace :

```
06-27 14:46:01.811: W/dalvikvm(20824): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d0c930)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 6, size is 4
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:390)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.widget.Spinner.makeAndAddView(Spinner.java:546)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:495)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:459)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-27 14:46:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(20824): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT :**

In the on Start, I bind to my service. Then, in onServiceConnected, I ask the service for configuration informations :

```
        try {
            remoteServiceMain.requeteLireConfig();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Then, still in the onServiceConnected, I define the layout :

```
spinner_outil = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_outil_layout);
spinner_outil.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    }
}
```

Then onServiceConnected is finished. Please note that I get the last log before error there.

**REDDIT :**

I do `setSelection(positionSaved);` after `spinner_outil.setAdapter(adapterOutil);`, and I set positionSaved when I get the answer from the service after calling :

```
    try {
        remoteServiceMain.requeteLireConfig();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`positionSaved` is sent by the Service, which takes it from a Configuration File. `positionSaved` is saved evrytime the user clicks on an Item of the spinner. The reason why I get it from the service and not directly from the File is that I use the same method for other things

Comment: What is `positionSaved` when you use `spinner_outil.setSelection(positionSaved);`? Is it 6?

Comment: It's the previous position chosen by the user. When I change the file, I set IN THE FILE the position to 0, and then, in the activity, I take this value and do a `spinner_outil.setSelection(positionSaved);`

Comment: please post more of Your code. The error comes definitly from positionSaved, but without seeing what You are doing with that, we can´t help.

Comment: shout? what has he done?

Comment: Oups, sorry if you thought I was shouting, I was just trying to put an accent on the fact that I change positionSaved in the file before reading it from the activity through a service

Comment: I'll post new code at the bottom of my question under the stack trace

Comment: ok, but what about Your Integer "positionSaved"? Fact is, You trying to get a position inside Your list that doesn´t exist. Please post the part where "positionSaved" is used and how do You get this value.